# MySQL connect to google app engine instance

Tags: mysql, sql, google-app-engine, client

I have a google app engine application and Cloud SQL set up, I have attached the application to the instance but now I have to connect my computer (MAC OS X) using MySQL client (the terminal) to the instance. According to the GAE tutorial:

```
shell> mysql --host=instance-IP --user=user-name --password

Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.5.31 (Google)
....
mysql>
```

But this is what happens (the host is the IP address of the instance) I dont know what to put as the username?:

```
Tom$ mysql --host=173.194.225.73--user=username --password
Enter password: 
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '173.194.225.73--user=username' (0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Extra space between the host and the --user?

Comment: Oh that actually worked thank you. But I am now getting a new error:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'151.231.235.228' (using password: YES)

Comment: I have authorised that network access to the instance, but I am unable to connect. What should the username be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the space to the IP --username you need to add in Cloud SQL -> Access Control -> Allowed Networks your IP address as an allowed IP address to access.